# What is the difference between `TabBarView` and `PageView` in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What is the difference between `TabBarView` and `PageView`  in Flutter?

I want to implement like this. And I know both can do.

[image]

From [flutter-examples](https://github.com/nisrulz/flutter-examples/tree/master/using_bottom_nav_bar)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- TabBarView is the widget used when each tab has different
  functionalty. TabBarView works with a TabController.
  For example, WhatsApp has three tabs with different
  functionality, like Chats, Status and Calls.
- PageView works with a PageController. You can use it for a Slider,
  or for creating a carousel.

If each page has a different UI and functionality, use a TabBarView.
If they have the same UI and functionalty and only page data differs, then you can go with a PageView.

**TabBarView for:**

[image]

**PageView for:**

[image]

Comment: Wording that starts from "Each page..." could be improved. Had a hard time decrypting that sentence.

Comment: Tried improving the English a bit, should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If each page has a different UI then use TabBarView. If each page has the same UI and only the data differs, then you can use PageView. Obviously if the UI is different then the functionality is different.